# fixed header blocking content below

Tags: html, css, fixed

So, I have a header which I have set as fixed. I have a list of items underneath it which scroll, but the header stays intact. However, one of the issues I'm facing is that the list is covered by the fixed header at the very top, obstructing the first item of the list.

I've tried adding "margin-top:55px;" to the container holding the list of items, but doing so hides the scrollbar behind the header, which is not very nice to look at. How could I display the header and list without it being obstructed?

Any help would be most appreciated.

```css
body.campaign-body {   height: 100%;  overflow-y: scroll; }
.container.campaign-header { position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000; background: #000; width: 100%; height: 55px; color:#fff;""}
.container.scroll-campaign-list { /*margin-top: 55px;*/ }
```

```html
<body class="campaign-body">
  <div class="container campaign-header">
    <div class="row admin-header">
        <div class="header-title">
            <h4 class="white-txt header-name">LISTING</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container scroll-campaign-list" id="campaigns-list">
    <div class="row campaigns">
        <div class="twelve columns list-items">
            <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
            <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row campaigns">
        <div class="twelve columns list-items">
            <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
            <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr><div class="row campaigns">
        <div class="twelve columns list-items">
            <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
            <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr><div class="row campaigns">
        <div class="twelve columns list-items">
            <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
            <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr><div class="row campaigns">
        <div class="twelve columns list-items">
            <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
            <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr><div class="row campaigns">
        <div class="twelve columns list-items">
            <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
            <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr><div class="row campaigns">
        <div class="twelve columns list-items">
            <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
            <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr><div class="row campaigns">
        <div class="twelve columns list-items">
            <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
            <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr><div class="row campaigns">
        <div class="twelve columns list-items">
            <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
            <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Why not give the `container.campaign-header` a top attribute i.e. `top:0;`. Then if you give the `.container.scroll-campaign-list` a `margin-top`

Comment: have you tried `padding-top`? I forget which one uses the scroll bar...  Anyways, you may need to make your scrollable content inside of a container, then make what I call a `push` container above that.  Position them absolutely) and you should be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, reset body margin:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Next, set padding-top (not margin-top) for `scroll-campaign-list`:

```
.container.scroll-campaign-list {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a "blocker" do this before:

HTML:

```
<div class="blocker"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Matches your header height */
.blocker { height: 55px; };
```

All you are doing it putting an invisible div underneath the header

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/btv5bjfd/

Answer (score 0):

I've posted your code in a fiddle to make is a bit easier to work with.
Below is the fiddle link with the results, take a look and tell me if it's what you were looking for.

I've made your header attack to the top of the page which made me able to add a margin to the list.

```
.container.campaign-header { position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000; background: #000; width: 100%; height: 55px; color:#fff; top:0;}
.container.scroll-campaign-list {margin-top: 75px; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m4fw7mk1

Answer (score 0):

If you want your scroll bar to not scroll "through" the header, you're going to have to make a fixed content area which will handle the scrolling, rather than the body which normally handles the scrolling.

Check [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2n6fb2zc/1/) for the basics.

Make sure you have zero margin and padding on your body

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Then, make sure your header is fixed **to the top and left**

```
.campaign-header {
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Then your campaign scroll list is going to be a fixed content container that is 100% height minus the height of the header, positioned at the bottom of the header and allows scrolling

```
.scroll-campaign-list {
    position:fixed;
    top:55px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:calc(100% - 55px);
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2n6fb2zc/3/) with your content in it

Answer (score -1):

I think that it is better to have different classes. So I have deleted the .container class.

```css
 body.campaign-body {   height: 100%;  overflow-y: scroll; }
    .campaign-header { position: fixed; top: 0;
        z-index: 1000; background: #000; width: 100%; height: 55px; color:#fff;""}
    .scroll-campaign-list { margin-top: 95px; }
```

```html
 <body class="campaign-body">
      <div class="campaign-header">
        <div class="row admin-header">
            <div class="header-title">
                <h4 class="white-txt header-name">LISTING</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="scroll-campaign-list" id="campaigns-list">
        <div class="row campaigns">
            <div class="twelve columns list-items">
                <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
                <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row campaigns">
            <div class="twelve columns list-items">
                <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
                <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr><div class="row campaigns">
            <div class="twelve columns list-items">
                <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
                <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr><div class="row campaigns">
            <div class="twelve columns list-items">
                <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
                <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr><div class="row campaigns">
            <div class="twelve columns list-items">
                <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
                <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr><div class="row campaigns">
            <div class="twelve columns list-items">
                <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
                <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr><div class="row campaigns">
            <div class="twelve columns list-items">
                <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
                <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr><div class="row campaigns">
            <div class="twelve columns list-items">
                <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
                <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr><div class="row campaigns">
            <div class="twelve columns list-items">
                <h5 class="white-txt campaign-name">Blah blah</h5>
                <p class="campaign-question grey-txt">Blah blah</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
     </div>
     </body>
```

Comment: I took -1 and I don't understand the reason. The questioner doesn't explain all or enough. In future probably I will not answer anyone with this kind of image profile and name.